# Ansible playbook to checkout to detach branch and merge in branch

Tags: ansible

I am new to ansible. Assuming I am on a develop branch, I m trying to execute something akin to:

```
git checkout --detach
git merge branch-for-pr
```

This should create a detached state that mimics a pull request being merged in. So far I have:

```
- name: get to detached
  sudo: no
  git: >
    refspec=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
    detach=True
```

However I see nothing in the docs about how to perform a merge.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The [Git module](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-modules-core/blob/devel/source_control/git.py) does not appear to currently support a merge command.

One way to accomplish the merge you're describing would be to use the [command module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/command_module.html):

```
- name: git merge branch-for-pr
  command: git merge branch-for-pr
  args:
    chdir: path/to/your/repo
```